# Objective C - What is the difference between IMP and function pointer?

Tags: objective-c, swizzling, method-swizzling

I recently started a project where I require to do swizzling.

After going through many tutorials I got a question, What is the difference between Implementation and function pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From memory, an IMP is a memory-address just like a function pointer, and can be invoked just like an ordinary C function. However it is guaranteed to use objective-C messaging convention, where:

- The first argument is the object to operate on (self).
- The second argument is the `_cmd` (SELECTOR) to be invoked. I believe this is so to support dynamic features, such as ObjC message forwarding where we could wrap the original implementation in a proxy, say to start a transaction or perform a security check, or, for a Cocoa specific example, add some property observation cruft, by magic, at run-time. While we already have the function signature, I could be helpful, in some cases, to know "how did I get here?" with the *message* signature.
- Following arguments, if any, are according to the method contract.

Comment: I think it's `self` *then* `SEL`.

Comment: @jasper In all the tutorials first argument is self and the second is _cmd.

Comment: Oops, fixed thanks. Probably someone will give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Not sure there is much more to say about it :)

Comment: I added a little rant (hopefully correct) about why SEL is there, when we already have a function signature.

Comment: @JasperBlues I already came to the above conclusion after reading http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/02/imp-of-current-method.html

Comment: I'm looking if they are almost same.

Comment: This is correct; an `IMP` _is_ a function pointer, pointing to the contents of an ObjC method. The only thing that might be added here would be its definition as a type: `typedef id (*IMP)(id, SEL, ...)`, in [objc.h in the runtime library](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-680/runtime/objc.h). @bikram990 See also [Apple's ObjC Runtime Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH3g-116261)